# Knockout Viewmodel + selecteditem -> nested list "not defined"

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I have a viewModel

```
var viewModel = {
    Classes: ko.observableArray(data),
    addPerson: function() {
        SelectedClass.Persons.push(new Person(SelectedClass, " ", " "));
    },
    SelectedClass: ko.observable({
        Persons: ko.observableArray([]),
        Location: ko.observable("")
    }),
 };
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I bind a master detail view with Classes. Select a class to get a list of "Persons" in that class.

I have a button to add a person to the Class.
When I try to click it, I get:

**ReferenceError: Persons is not defined.**

Why can't it find the nested list of Persons inside SelectedClass and push to that?

I have created a fiddle with some test data.
http://jsfiddle.net/alexintime/n77ujya3/2/
Although in the fiddle I cannot get the show details button to work, and thus not fill "SelectedClass".
but atleast it's something.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, any access to an object property from a member of the whole object should be qualified with `this` (it's not the case of C#, where there're few edge cases where you need to use `this` explicitly):

```
// Check that you need to get "SelectedClass" property value like a function call 
// (Knockout's getter function):
addPerson: function() {
    this.SelectedClass().Persons.push(new Person(this.SelectedClass(), " ", " "));
}
```

## Update, issue #2

`this.SelectedClass` is an observable property. In order to access `Persons` property, you need to obtain `SelectedClass` property value like a function: `this.SelectedClass()`!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, BUT unfortunately I'm still getting the same error

Comment: @AlexInTime What's the value of `this` in `addPerson` function body?

Comment: a Class Object, but the problem is with the "Persons" which is defined in "SelectedClass" - why can I not access it?

Comment: totally works, although my UI isn't updated - it's working with
viewModel.SelectedClass().Persons.push(new Person...
Shouldn't ui update when I use ko.observable?

Comment: @AlexInTime It depends on the binding configuration, maybe I take a look this afternoon, and I'm glad that at least you learned a new KO leason today ;)

Comment: I created a remove person function pretty much matching the addPerson (ofcourse with remove and not a "new person", duuuh).
But alas, not working. TypeError: viewModel.SelectedClass(...).Persons.remove is not a function

Comment: @AlexInTime AFAIK an array doesn't own a `remove` method

Comment: from:http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html
myObservableArray.remove(someItem) removes all values that equal someItem and returns them as an array

Comment: @AlexInTime Ask another question about your current issue. You'll get a better solution, comments are meant to add suggestions or discuss some issue with a question or answer